# I can't understand why my variable is undefined

Tags: php, laravel

Why in "action" URL is writing my page ID and when I want to DD() it tells that variable is undefined
When I go to edit page , domainPage->id show null
Look at blade

```
{{dd($domainPage->id)}}
        <form action="{{route('admin.domain.update', ['domainPage'=> $domainPage->id])}}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    @method('put')
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    @include('admin.domains.form')
                    <div class="form-group border-top pt-3">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-block  btn-primary" >Update</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

This is controller

```
 public function edit(DomainPage $domainPage)
    {
        return view('admin.domains.edit', ['domainPage'=> $domainPage]);
    }
```

This is route

```
Route::resource('domain', 'Admin\DomainPageController')
```

Comment: I think because you set domain segment is `domain` and you model is `DomainPage`, so laravel can not understand which model need to be binding for you: https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#implicit-binding.

Comment: do you have "id" in domin model field list???

Answer (score 1):

Your model binding is not loading, you have to name your model binding class the same as your api resource.

```
public function edit(DomainPage $domain) {
    return view('admin.domains.edit', ['domain'=> $domain]);
}
```